# Is there anyway to detect hovering gesture on `BarMark` in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to implement a way to detect hovering gesture on `Chart` in SwiftUI.

At first I tried adding `.onHover()` modifier to `BarMark` like below, but it seems it doesn't work because `BarMark` does not conform to `View` Protocol while `.onHover()` is defined `View`.

```
Chart(modules) { module in
          BarMark(x: .value("name", module.name), y: .value("Score", module.score)).onHover { over in
             details = module.name
     } // gives error
}
```

So does that mean If I want to show additional data when user hover over the Chart graph, then I have to create my own Chart graph rather than using `Chart` from `Charts` framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this approach, using an `.chartOverlay` and `.onContinuousHover`.
You will have to adjust the location calculations to suit your purpose.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let measurement: [Measurement] = [
        Measurement(id: "1", val: 11.2),
        Measurement(id: "2", val: 22.2),
        Measurement(id: "3", val: 38.2)
    ]
    
    @State var select = "0"
    @State var isHovering = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(measurement) { data in
                BarMark(x: .value("Time", data.id), y: .value("val", data.val))
                    .foregroundStyle(select == data.id ? .blue : .red)
            }
        }
        .chartOverlay { proxy in
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .onContinuousHover { phase in
                            switch phase {
                            case .active(let location):
                                bar(at: location, proxy: proxy, geometry: geometry)
                                isHovering = true
                            case .ended:
                                isHovering = false
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func bar(at location: CGPoint, proxy: ChartProxy, geometry: GeometryProxy) {
        let xPosition = location.x - geometry[proxy.plotAreaFrame].origin.x
        let yPosition = location.y - geometry[proxy.plotAreaFrame].origin.y
        guard let month: String = proxy.value(atX: xPosition) else { return }
        guard let measure: Double = proxy.value(atY: yPosition) else { return }
        // more logic here ....
        select = month
    }
}

struct Measurement: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var val: Double
}
```

If you want to just tap on the `BarMarks`, see my other answer at: [How to change the color of BarView in SwiftUI charts when we tap on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74979520/how-to-change-the-color-of-barview-in-swiftui-charts-when-we-tap-on-it)

EDIT-1:

update for newer Swift version and to display `isHovering` value

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let measurement: [Measurement] = [
        Measurement(id: "1", val: 11.2),
        Measurement(id: "2", val: 22.2),
        Measurement(id: "3", val: 38.2)
    ]
    
    @State var select = ""
    
    @State var isHovering = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("isHovering: \(isHovering ? "true" : "false") ")
        Chart {
            ForEach(measurement) { data in
                BarMark(x: .value("Time", data.id), y: .value("val", data.val))
                    .foregroundStyle(select == data.id ? .blue : .red)
            }
        }
        .chartOverlay { proxy in
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .onContinuousHover { phase in
                            switch phase {
                            case .active(let location):
                                isHovering = barSelected(at: location, proxy: proxy, geometry: geometry)
                            case .ended:
                                select = ""
                                isHovering = false
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func barSelected(at location: CGPoint, proxy: ChartProxy, geometry: GeometryProxy) -> Bool {
        if let proxyFrame = proxy.plotFrame {
            let xPosition = location.x - geometry[proxyFrame].origin.x
            guard let month: String = proxy.value(atX: xPosition) else { return false }
            select = month
            // more logic here ....
            return true
        } else {
            select = ""
            return false
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me

Comment: Can you explain what is not working.
 Does the red bars not change to blue when your pointer is over them.

Comment: the isHovering is not updating to true

Comment: updated my answer and show `isHovering` value. Let me know if `isHovering` does not change for you.